Langchain OpenAI .with_structured_output() JSON mode
I am not sure what setting the method parameter to "json_mode" (i.e. method="json_mode") in with_structured_output() does. It seems to make no difference to the output.
The documentation gives two options:

structured_llm = model.with_structured_output(Joke)

and

structured_llm = model.with_structured_output(Joke, method="json_mode")

But for both, the output is an object of type Joke i.e.
Joke(setup='Why was the cat sitting on the computer?', punchline='To keep an eye on the mouse!')
and
Joke(setup='Why was the cat sitting on the computer?', punchline='Because it wanted to keep an eye on the mouse!')
respectively
Here is the link to that section in the documentation.
So what is the point of the method="json_mode"?
I tried running the code on my mahchine and confirmed that the output is indeed the same regardless of whether the json_mode is set or not.
I am expect some sort of difference in the output result.

Here the counterpart of "json mode" is the "function Calling mode".
with_structured_output documentation
The difference is the "function Calling mode" asks the LM to provide structured answers through the LLM's API (for example, openAI's JSON support).
The json mode does so by prompting the LM to answer in JSON format. This could be helpful if your LLM does not support a JSON function call.

JSON mode is a more basic version of the Structured Outputs feature.

JSON mode: ensures that model output is valid JSON
Structured Outputs: matches the model's output to the schema you specify

So, in most scenarios adding json_mode is redundant like in the example you used.
You can use JSON model in Chat Completions or Assistants API by setting:
response_format={ "type": "json_object" }

In this case you must specify in your chat that the response should be in JSON format.
Also, in function calling, JSON mode is always turned on.
See in more details here
